# how to apply CSS styles to blocks/tags inside a BoundField in a GridView

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style> .GridViewCell 
            {
            display:inline-block; 
        width:200; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvExportList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID #" DataFormatString="&nbsp;{0}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" />
    </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the `Text` field to be something like this:

[image]

I tried this but it didn't show the style applied for each `span`:

```
 <span  style='display:inline-block; width:100'>Word</span><span>Here</span>
    </br>
    <span  style='display:inline-block; width:100'>And</span><span>Here</span>
```

with `ItemStyle CSS` It applies the CSS style to the whole string, not how I want it:

```
<ItemStyle CssClass="GridViewCell" />
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How does your final HTML look like? The html that is generated by your asp.net...

Comment: @Dekel for the whole `gridview` or just the Text field? If you mean just the Text field, it looks like how I showed above at last.

Comment: asp.net generates html. `<asp:GridView` is **not** html... without looking at your html - it's impossible to help with the css.

Comment: @Dekel I added the HTML code.

Comment: You only added the `<html>` tags, not the output...

Comment: @Dekel i'm sorry, I didn't exactly understand what you meant. I attached a screenshot of the output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just &tab; will help?

Or if you'd rather have each word spaced out across the element.
Here is an example of doing it in css/html

css

```
div{
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:justify;
}

span{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<div>
  Lorem ipsum sit dolor
  <span> </span>
</div>
```

Reference: http://codepen.io/aakilfernandes/pen/IEAhF/